# Geoevent license file ecp

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-license-manager, geoevent-processor

I need the license file (.lic) of geoevent.

Answer (score 2):

License files of commercial products should be requested from their vendors.

In the case of the ArcGIS GeoEvent Server Extension for Server the [Pricing page](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/pricing) says:

> For more details, call [your local Esri office](http://www.esri.com/about-esri).

If your site is licensed, but you are not your site's administrative contact with Esri, then you should identify and contact your site's administrative contact using your organisation's internal procedures.